# Determine button clicked subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, onclick, subplot

Given a figure with multiple plots, is there a way to determine which of them was clicked with a mouse button?

E.g.

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax  = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.imshow(imsp0)

ax = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax.imshow(imsp1)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event",onclick_select)

def onclick_select(event):
  ... do something depending on the clicked subplot
```

Answer (score 6):

If you retain a handle to both axes, you may just query the axes in which the click has happened; e.g. `if event.inaxes == ax:`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

imsp0 = np.random.rand(10,10)
imsp1 = np.random.rand(10,10)

fig = plt.figure()

ax  = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.imshow(imsp0)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.imshow(imsp1)

def onclick_select(event):
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        print ("event in ax")
    elif event.inaxes == ax2:
        print ("event in ax2")

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event",onclick_select)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible at least by applying the following steps:

- the onclick event has attributes `x` and `y` carrying the pixel coordinates from the corner of the figure
- these coordinates can be converted into figure coordinates by using `fig.transFigure.inverted().transform((x,y))`
- you can get the bounding box of each subplot by `bb=ax.get_position()`
- iterate through all subplots (axes) of the image
- you can test whether the click is within the area of this bounding box by `bb.contains(fx,fy)`, where `fx` and `fy` are the button click coordinates transformed into image position

For more info on the onclick event: http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html
For more info on the coordinate transformations: http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html