# python get coordinates (pixels) of corresponding points from clicks

Tags: image, python-3.x, matplotlib, onclick

I have two images which I want to do the following using python 3.6

1- plot both images side by side
2- click on one image and output the corresponding pixel coordinates
3- click on the second image and get the corresponding pixel coordinates

note: this question is different because it has to work on two images by finding the axis the click event is happening.

I think the best way is to have a function that identifies which axis i am clicking on and gets the clicked coordinates. I couldn't find much of a resources for two images, mostly what I found is on one image.

Comment: This are really two questions here. First is how to get the pixel coordinates, this is shown in the first two duplicates. There would not actually be any need to distinguish the two plots, but if you still want to do it, the second question on how to check for which plot has been clicked is answered in the third duplicate.

Comment: Finding the axes in which the click has happened is done like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45308346/4124317) to the third duplicate question.

Comment: thank you. Built a rough version based on these examples which works for the moment.

Comment: You are always welcome to ask specific questions about code that you have a problem with. Just make sure the question has a [mcve] available. Otherwise questions will often be duplicates of off-topic here.